# Get current EditText reference in InputMethodService

Tags: android, mobile-development

I developed a CustomKeyboard, to be used in any application for Android, that the pressure of a key opens a running Activity recognition.

At the end of the recognition the Activity closes and I need to write the recognized text in EditText that opened the keyboard (any EditText such as Sms App), but I can not because it is probably no longer active.

How can I get a reference to the active EditText that opened my keyboard, and then use it later to write the recognized text?

EDIT:
sorry... the code is below

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{

private KeyboardView _kv;
private Keyboard _keyboard;
private InputMethodManager _inputMethodManager;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {

    _kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    _kv.setKeyboard(_keyboard);
    _kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Const.NOTIFICATION));

    return _kv;
}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    switch(primaryCode){

        case 1010:
            // starts View for Barcode scanning
            _lastEditorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();

            _lastBarcode = null;

            BarcodeActivity mainactivity = new BarcodeActivity();

            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(SoftKeyboard.this, BarcodeActivity.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);

            Log.i("Key","Open BarCode Activity");
            //ic.commitText(String.valueOf(_lastBarcode),1);

            new WaitForBarcode(ic, _inputMethodManager).execute("");
            break;

        ...
    }
}

    private class WaitForBarcode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private InputConnection _icn;
    private InputMethodManager _inputMethodManager;

    public WaitForBarcode(InputConnection icn, InputMethodManager inputMethodManager) {
        _icn = icn;
        _inputMethodManager = inputMethodManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        _inputMethodManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        _inputMethodManager.restartInput(_kv);
        _kv.setActivated(true);

        Log.i("Barcode-last", _lastBarcode);

        _icn = getCurrentInputConnection();
        _icn.commitText(String.valueOf(_lastBarcode),1);
    }

};
```

in onKey() I start the BarcodeActivity, this one work's perfectly.

At the onPostExecute I have right barcode in the _lastBarcode field, but when I try to post on EditText is not there ;(

**SOLVED**
Putting a delay of 1sec on doInBackground (just to give to the System time to close previous Activity) and forcing to re-open keyboard, the commitText works.

Code is:

```
private class WaitForBarcode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private InputConnection _icn;
    private InputMethodManager _inputMethodManager;

    public WaitForBarcode(InputConnection icn, InputMethodManager inputMethodManager) {
        _icn = icn;
        _inputMethodManager = inputMethodManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        while (_lastBarcode == null) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
        }

        return _lastBarcode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        _inputMethodManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        _inputMethodManager.restartInput(_kv);
        getInputView().setActivated(true);

        Log.i("Barcode-last", _lastBarcode);

        final InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic != null && _lastBarcode != null) {
            ic.beginBatchEdit();
            ic.commitText(_lastBarcode, 0);
            ic.endBatchEdit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: We cannot help much without seeing your code.

Comment: you could save it to a static value? or probably just send it to another activity?

Comment: @Tirolel yep, the value is saved on _lastBarcode. But I want put it in the currently focused EditText.

Comment: @user8 sorry... you're right. I modified the request with the code.

Comment: you can only get `android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo`, not `EditText`

Comment: @pskink there is an alternative way to enter text on the EditText, even without having direct access?

Comment: without `InputMethodService`? no

Comment: @pskink I'm using InputMethodService... but on onKey works, from other method (AsyncTask.onPostExecute), no...

Comment: was this ever figured out? I implemented this and it only partially works (put the text in the clipboard, then have to hit paste when the popup edittext is closed)